# Error with nested environment and forced linebreak inside tabbing

Tags: errors, line-breaking, environments, tabbing

I reduced the offending code to this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{foo}{}{}
\begin{tabbing}
\begin{foo}
bar\\
\end{foo}
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

I am getting `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`, in line 9: `bar\\`.

Is there something special about the tabbing environment that I'm overlooking?

Comment: \\ is used by the `tabbing` environment to break lines, so when it is encountered inside `foo`, `tabbing` gets confused and thinks that it is a linebreak.

Comment: But why is it throwing an error instead of rendering a linebreak?

Comment: Because `\begin{foo}` is not ended before the linebreak and you get `forgotten \endgroup`.

Comment: @karlkoeller Can you supply an answer?

Answer (score 3):

`\\` is used by the `tabbing` environment to break lines.

Since you've issued it inside the environment `foo`, the environment is not ended before the linebreak and `tabbing` gets confused. That's the reason of the error `forgotten \endgroup`.

If you let `foo` end before the linebreak, you don't get the error, as in following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{foo}{}{}
\begin{tabbing}
\begin{foo}\end{foo}\\
bar\\
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```